# Jekyll nested include with for loop

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'd like to use a `{% for %}` loop in an included file, to avoid repeating logic to create the loop array (it's an `assign` with multiple `where_exp`s).

But I'd like to use different content depending on where I include the loop, so sometimes I will do this:

```
{% for i in a %}
<li>{{ i.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

and sometimes:

```
{% for i in a %}
<loc>{{ i.url }}</loc>
{% endfor %}
```

How can I achieve this? So far I have to put each of the inner contents in their own template, so I would have files like below, but I'd like to avoid the extra `template` files, and just keep that content in the appropriate `main` file:

**html_template.html:**

```
<li>{{ i.name }}</li>
```

**xml_template.xml:**

```
<loc>{{ i.url }}</loc>
```

**page_loop.html:**

```
{% assign a = "logic I don't want to repeat" %}
{% for i in a %}
{% include {{ include.inner_template }} %}
{% endfor %}
```

**html_main.html:**

```
{% include page_loop.html inner_template="html_template.html" %}
```

**xml_main.xml:**

```
{% include page_loop.html inner_template="xml_template.xml" %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would probably be another more *elegant* (?) solution developing a plugin, but quickly modifying your code, in `_includes/page_loop.html`:

```
{% assign a = "something" %}
{% for i in a %}
{%if include.type == "name"%}
<li>{{ i.name }}</li>
{%else if include.type == "url"%}
<loc>{{ i.url }}</loc>
{%endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Then each time you include `page_loop.html` pass an additional parameter specifying which type of output you want:

```
{% include page_loop.html type="name" %}
```

or

```
{% include page_loop.html type="url" %}
```

Comment: This way occurred to me as I wrote the question, but still has the same problem for me that the "inner" content is separated from the surrounding content. Thanks though!

Comment: @cmbuckley yes it doesn't look so clean, may be with real data would be easier to figure out another alternatives, anyway the above answer saves it from using two extra templates though

Comment: This is pretty close to real data. In a site served by GitHub pages, I'm filtering `site.github.public_respositories` in a few places, sometimes to display in the site map, and other to display a list of projects. [Here's an example](https://github.com/cmbuckley/cmbuckley.github.io/commit/3851cfe233a83598b26e2da7de595caab3c1cc37) where I repeat the assign.